# validating an appropriate url

Tags: php, validation, url

The form:

```
echo '<form id="newForm" name="newForm" action="../../../admin/info/apps" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return createOrUpdate(); return validateURL();">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="submit" />';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Update" style="margin-right: 5px;" />';
```

The function:

```
function validateURL()
{
  var http = document.newForm.URL.value.indexOf("http://");
  var https = document.newForm.URL.value.indexOf("https://");
  if (http!=0 || https!=0)
  {
    alert("Not a valid URL: must start with http://");
    return false;
  }
}
```

URL is the name of the input box

I know that you can do two onClick methods, but for some reason it isn't working. I am trying to look at the input value to check that the URL starts with a proper beginning.

My createOrUpdate function works perfectly, but it looks like the validateForm function is never called. Any advice?

Comment: The first `return` stops the execution...

Comment: @user2572833 Well I for one, do/did not see any other mention of `validateForm` anywhere else except in your *"but it looks like the validateForm function is never called."* I think you meant `validateURL` (wink)

Comment: Hm... sound like @DCoder has a point there. Good catch.

Comment: Is there a way to return them both?

Comment: If `createOrUpdate` returns true/false, then: `return createOrUpdate() && validateURL();`. Presuming that is the right order in which you want to execute those functions, of course.

Comment: `onsubmit="function(){if(validateURL()){return createOrUpdate()}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different function to test both the returns of your two functions

**html**

```
<form id="newForm" name="newForm" action="../../../admin/info/apps" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return myFunction();">';
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
   var first = createOrUpdate(); 
   var second = validateURL();
   return (first && second);
}
```

You could also do as DCoder mentions in his comment and do the `return createOrUpdate() && validateURL();` inline, I did it this way to keep the inline code to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be better to put both functions into one function, because I think it is breaking up on the first return, maybe you should try this:

```
function validate(){
    createOrUpdate(); 
    validateURL();
}
```

And remove the return from both functions.

Comment: That won't prevent the form from submitting if `validateURL()` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Combine both functions into one:

```
function validateForm() {
    return createOrUpdate() && validateURL();
}
```

And this should be the [`onsubmit` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3) of your form: `onsubmit="return validateForm();"`.

Also, I don't see any field with name `URL` in your form. Are you sure it is indeed there?